# Performance of inline component instance as prop value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, components, react-props

So, we know this can cause excessive renders in React...

```js
<ThingContainer
  onClick={event => { /* do stuff */ }}
/>
```

But, what about this?

```js
<ThingContainer
  thingComponent={<Thing />}
/>
```

And what about this?

```js
<ThingContainer
  renderThingComponent={specialProps => <Thing {...specialProps} />}
/>
```

Looks like a new instance of `Thing` (or new inline render function) is created for each render. Does that mean the value of the `thingComponent` (or `renderThingComponent`) prop is new for each new render, causing ThingContainer to re-render?

Comment: in your first codeblock `onClick={e => .. }`  nothing about that will cause excessive renders. And it's not the props that cause `Thing` to rerender, it's whenever its parent re-renders, it will rerender all its children. if you memoize a component it might not render unless its props change but you need to explicitly do that. is there a reason you are worrying about too many renders?

Comment: You might be conflating renders with performance. It's only when the DOM actually updates does render performance matter (or if you're rendering many hundreds / thousands of components on every update)

Comment: @azium Every time the parent renders it means ThingContainer will also render because of the anonymous function as the prop value. New function each time.

Comment: Of course, you're right, unneeded renders do not cause performance, but they can, particularly when renders do occur frequently. I'm asking from a general perspective though - we know it's not optimal. I'm aware of how to get around it, how to memoize, and that this isn't an issue until it's an issue. Suppose my question is more along the lines of, "Does react handle this case any differently than the anonymous function, or do the same (albeit nominal) caveats apply"?

Comment: Components always re-render if their parents re-render, regardless if props are different or not.